# Unable to compare string with regex using test operator in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, git

i am trying to restrict users to give an unformatted message in git commit-message window. For that i created some formatted regex and trying to put that one in commit-msg hook.
But i am unable to compare the git commit-message string with below regex.

Could you please help me to resolve this ?

```
regex="[A-Z]{3,}-[0-9][0-9]* #time (?:[0-9]+[wdhm])+ #comment (.|\n)*"
file=`cat $1`

echo $regex
echo $file

if [[ "$file" =~ $regex ]]; then
        echo "Valid date"
    else
        echo "Pre-Commit hook is failed. commit-message format not met regex    pattern Eg: TEST-123 #time 2w #comment added second line"
        exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Welcome on StackExchange, I've [edit]ed your question to make it more readable. Take the time to read the [tour] to know a bit better how the site does work and how you could improve your question. Have a nice day.

Comment: If you have got any error running the script, please edit the question and include it in the question.

Comment: What does the actual string look like? The one you're trying to match against that regex pattern

Comment: Bash does not support Perl-like regular expressions.

Comment: actual string would be like this:   TEST-123 #time 2w #comment added second line

Comment: just i want to compare the commit-msg string should be compared with above pattern. Means, any other methods are there to do this, ex: grep -iqE "$regex" $file;    Thanks in advanced for your help

Comment: Also, standard Unix tools don't match regular expressions across multiple lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `(?:...)` is a perl regexp operator. If you want to use those in a shell, you need `zsh` or `ksh93`. `bash` has no support for them. Anyway here, the standard ERE `(...)` could be used instead.
- What `\n` matches is also unspecified in POSIX extended regexp which `bash` uses (on most systems, it will match on `n` only) but note that anyway `.` also matches on the newline character in EREs
- anyway, regexps are not anchored in the `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` operator, so any `<anything>*` at the end would be redundant as it's sure to match as it matches at least the empty string.
- what `[A-Z]` matches outside of the POSIX locale is pretty random in practice. It will likely match on the 26 uppercase letters of the English alphabet, but probably a lot more characters (even possibly sequences of characters)¹
- Same for `[0-9]`  which depending on the locale and the system matches on decimal digits and possibly more random characters.
- unquoted parameter expansions has a very special meaning in shells, there's no reason you'd want to keep those `$1`/`$regex...` unquoted there.
- When passing arbitrary arguments to commands, you need to make sure they are not treated as options. So `file=$(cat -- "$1")` or `file=$(cat < "$1")` or with ksh/zsh/bash: `file=$(<"$1")` (though it may fail to return a non-zero exit status upon failure).
- `echo` can't be used for arbitrary data
- it's a good idea to check for the success/failure of a command before carrying on to the next.
- errors should generally go to stderr.

```
uppercase=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
digit=0123456789
regexp="^[$uppercase]{3,}-[$digit]+ #time ([$digit]+[wdhm])+ #comment "

file=$(cat < "$1") || exit
printf '%s\n' "regexp: $regexp" "file: $file"

if [[ "$file" =~ $regexp ]]; then
  echo valid
else
  echo >&2 invalid
  exit 1
fi
```

A few extra notes:

- command substitution `$(cat < "$1")` above strips *all* trailing newline characters. So would remove trailing empty lines from the content of the file.
- `bash` contrary to `zsh` can't store the NUL character in its variables. If the input file contains some, they will be discarded (Which is probably just as well) with a warning message.

---

<sup>¹ On my GNU system, in a `en_GB.UTF-8` locale (typical in Britain), it matches on at least ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝĀĂĄĆĈĊČĎĐĒĔĖĘĚĜĞĠĢĤĦĨĪĬĮİĲĴĶĹĻĽĿŁŃŅŇŊŌŎŐŒŔŖŘŚŜŞŠŢŤŦŨŪŬŮŰŲŴŶŸƁƆƇƊƎƏƐƓƘƟƠƢƯƳǄǅǇǈǊǋǍǏǑǓǕǗǙǛǞǠǢǤǦǨǪǬǱǲǴǶǷǸǺǼǾȀȂȄȆȈȊȌȎȐȒȘȚȜȞȦȨȪȬȮȰȲḀḂḄḆḈḊḌḎḐḒḔḖḘḚḜḞḠḢḤḦḨḪḬḮḰḲḴḶḸḺḼḾṀṂṄṆṈṊṌṎṐṒṔṖṘṚṜṞṠṢṤṦṨṪṬṮṰṲṴṶṸṺṼṾẀẂẄẆẈẊẌẎẠẢẤẦẨẪẬẮẰẲẴẶẸẺẼẾỀỂỄỆỈỊỌỎỐỒỔỖỘỚỜỞỠỢỤỦỨỪỬỮỰỲỴỶỸ</sup>